# How do I create an external build job using the Gitlab API and how do I update its status?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

If I have a webhook reciever, how do I update the status of my webhook job (which can be a build process) through the API?

I am not using the gitlab runner feature for this aspect because it has to run on an external, third party server.